# OpenGL texturing, black square

Tags: c, linux, opengl, glsl

I'm trying to figure out the right way to render a single texture in OpenGL, I've made some progress but I'm only getting a black square.
I'm just not sure if there's something I'm not doing or if I'm not doing things in the correct order or maybe I've just made a mistake somewhere. All of the articles on the internet seem to say completely different things and the code is always split into tiny samples so I can never figure out what should go in the main loop and what shouldn't.

First off, here's what I have so far.
I load the image using FreeImage:

```
FIBITMAP *load_image(image_data *image)
{
    image->texture_id = 0;
    FreeImage_Initialise(FALSE);
    FIBITMAP *bitmap = NULL;
    FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT format = FreeImage_GetFIFFromFilename(image->path);

    if (!(bitmap = FreeImage_Load(
                    format,
                    image->path,
                    PNG_DEFAULT)))
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    glGenTextures(1, &(image->texture_id));
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, image->texture_id);
    glTexImage2D(
            GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            0,
            GL_BGR,
            FreeImage_GetWidth(bitmap),
            FreeImage_GetHeight(bitmap),
            0,
            GL_BGR,
            GL_UNSIGNED_INT,
            bitmap);
    FreeImage_Unload(bitmap);
    return bitmap;
}
```

And then here I have my main program loop:

```
void main_loop(
        image_data *image,
        shader_info *vertex_shader,
        shader_info *fragment_shader)
{
    /* Create variables to house vertex-array/vertex-buffer object names. */
    GLuint vArray, vBuffer, program, uniform_mytexture;

    /* NDC (x, y) pair for each vertex. */
    GLfloat vertices[4][2] = {
        {-0.90, -0.90},
        {0.90, -0.90},
        {-0.90, 0.90},
        {0.90, 0.90}};

    printf("%s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));

    /*
     * Allocates OpenGL memory, and binds vArray and vBuffer
     * to that memory for use as VAO and VBO names, repectively.
     */
    program = initialize_image(
            &vArray,
            &vBuffer,
            vertices,
            sizeof(vertices),
            vertex_shader,
            fragment_shader);

    /* Main display loop */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window.glfw_window))
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glClearColor(0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0);
        glViewport(0, 0, window.width, window.height);
        glUseProgram(program);
        glBindVertexArray(vArray);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, image->texture_id);
        uniform_mytexture = glGetUniformLocation(program, "mytexture");
        glUniform1i(uniform_mytexture, GL_TEXTURE0);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window.glfw_window);
        glfwPollEvents();
        glFlush();
    }
    return;
}
```

As you can see I do most of the glGen* and glBind* stuff in initialize_image(), which looks like this:

```
int initialize_image(
        GLuint*vArray,
        GLuint *vBuffer,
        GLfloat vertices[][2],
        int size,
        shader_info *vertex_shader,
        shader_info *fragment_shader)
{
    GLuint vShader, fShader, program, link_ok;
    GLint attribute_vpos, attribute_texcoord;
    const char *attribute_name_vpos = "vertex_position", *attribute_name_texcoord = "texcoord";

    glGenVertexArrays(1, vArray);
    glBindVertexArray(*vArray);
    glGenBuffers(1, vBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, *vBuffer);
    glBufferData(
            GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
            size,
            vertices,
            GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    vertex_shader->content = load_shader(vertex_shader->path);
    fragment_shader->content = load_shader(fragment_shader->path);
    vShader = compile_shader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertex_shader->content);
    fShader = compile_shader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragment_shader->content);
    program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(program, vShader);
    glAttachShader(program, fShader);
    glLinkProgram(program);
    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &link_ok);

    if (!link_ok)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Shader linkage failed.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    attribute_vpos = glGetAttribLocation(program, attribute_name_vpos);

    if (attribute_vpos == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Attribute binding failed.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glVertexAttribPointer(
            attribute_vpos,
            2,
            GL_FLOAT,
            GL_FALSE,
            0,
            BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(attribute_vpos);

    attribute_texcoord = glGetAttribLocation(program, attribute_name_texcoord);

    if (attribute_texcoord == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Attribute binding failed.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(attribute_texcoord);

    GLuint texture_vbo;
    GLfloat texture_coords[4][2] = {
        {-1.0, -1.0},
        {1.0, -1.0},
        {-1.0, 1.0},
        {1.0, 1.0}};

    glGenBuffers(1, &texture_vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texture_vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(texture_coords), texture_coords, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(attribute_texcoord);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texture_vbo);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
            attribute_texcoord,
            2,
            GL_FLOAT,
            GL_FALSE,
            0,
            0);

    return program;
}
```

And here is my vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec4 vertex_position;
attribute vec2 texcoord;
varying vec2 f_texcoord;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = vertex_position;
    f_texcoord = texcoord;
    return;
}
```

And the fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 fragment_color;
varying vec2 f_texcoord;
uniform sampler2D mytexture;

void main(void)
{
    fragment_color = texture2D(mytexture, f_texcoord);
    return;
}
```

I'm sorry to dump so much code, I can't really pinpoint where I went wrong so I didn't want to leave stuff out.
If anybody can point me in the right direction I'd be really grateful.

I've been trying to figure out how to do this for days. I feel so incompetent for spending so much time on one of the most basic features of OpenGL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of issues in this code:

1. As far as I could find, `GL_BGR` is not valid as an internal texture format. Also, specifying `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` as the type for `glTexImage2D()` would mean that *each component* is an unsigned int, while your texture loading routine most likely provides unsigned bytes for the components. And `bitmap` is a pointer to a `FIBITMAP` object, while the last argument needs to be a pointer to the actual image data. So the call should be:

   ```
   glTexImage2D(
       GL_TEXTURE_2D,
       0,
       GL_RGB8,
       FreeImage_GetWidth(bitmap),
       FreeImage_GetHeight(bitmap),
       0,
       GL_BGR,
       GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
       FreeImage_GetBits(bitmap));
   ```
2. The value for the texture sampler uniform variable is wrong:

   ```
   glUniform1i(uniform_mytexture, GL_TEXTURE0);
   ```

   This needs to be the index of the texture unit, not the corresponding enum value. Replace the call by:

   ```
   glUniform1i(uniform_mytexture, 0);
   ```
3. The shader code uses some storage qualifiers that are not available in the core profile. `attribute` and `varying` are not valid in the core profile. `attribute` is replaced by `in`, and `varying` by `out` in the vertex shader and `in` in the fragment shader. So the declarations in the vertex shader should be:

   ```
   layout(location = 0) in vec4 vertex_position;
   layout(location = 1) in vec2 texcoord;
   out vec2 f_texcoord;
   ```

   and in the fragment shader:

   ```
   out vec4 fragment_color;
   in vec2 f_texcoord;
   uniform sampler2D mytexture;
   ```

Comment: The `bitmap` variable in this code is an opaque FreeImage handle. You don't want to pass it directly to GL's data pointer in `glTexImage2D (...)`. There's a function: `FreeImage_GetBits (...)` that you need to call on it instead.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for starters, your image loading routine is completely wrong.

```
FIBITMAP *load_image(image_data *image)
{
    image->texture_id = 0;
    FreeImage_Initialise(FALSE);
    FIBITMAP *bitmap = NULL;
    FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT format = FreeImage_GetFIFFromFilename(image->path);

    if (!(bitmap = FreeImage_Load(
                    format,
                    image->path,
                    PNG_DEFAULT)))
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    glGenTextures(1, &(image->texture_id));
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, image->texture_id);
    glTexImage2D(
            GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            0,
            GL_BGR,
            FreeImage_GetWidth(bitmap),
            FreeImage_GetHeight(bitmap),
            0,
            GL_BGR,
            GL_UNSIGNED_INT, //I think FreeImage only loads bytes...
            bitmap); //...Hello, undefined behaviour...
    FreeImage_Unload(bitmap);
    return bitmap; //WHAT?
}
```

Also, FreeImage_Initialise and FreeImage_Deinitialise are meant to be called only once per program.

Comment: FreeImage supports 48,64,96 and 128-bit images in addition to the more traditional sizes (1,4,8,16,24,32). It absolutely has to support more than just bytes. But in this case since this is a PNG, and PNG's largest RGB image is 48-bit (16-bit per-channel) you are right (`GL_UNSIGNED_INT` is wrong).

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure if you are loading a PNG, you do not want `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` for the pixel data type (that would imply a 96-bit RGB image). Instead, you probably want `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` (24-bit).

#### Change your call to `glTexImage2D` to this:

```
glTexImage2D(
        GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        0,
        GL_RGB,
        FreeImage_GetWidth  (bitmap),
        FreeImage_GetHeight (bitmap),
        0,
        GL_BGR,
        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, // Assumption: FreeImage_GetBPP (bitmap) == 24
        FreeImage_GetBits (bitmap));
```

Often times when reading a 24-bit RGB image you have to change GL's unpack alignment from 4-byte to 1-byte, but FreeImage guarantees some desired behavior I will illustrate below (in case you encountered any examples that called `glPixelStorei (GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)` -- they do not apply here).

#### [FreeImage 3.13.1 documentation](http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs148-10-summer/docs/FreeImage3131.pdf) - Bitmap function reference - p. 14

> In FreeImage each scanline starts at a **32-bit boundary** for performance reasons.

I suggest you browse through the rest of that API reference while you are at it. You can use many of those functions to eliminate things like the 24-bit image assumption I made above.